# Is gauge invariance the same as gauge symmetry?

Tags: terminology, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I am studying Gauge theory using [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_gauge_theory) and need a little clarification on the difference between gauge symmetry and gauge invariance. For sure it has probably already been addressed on this site, although I can't quite seem to find it.

Perhaps gauge invariance is an adjective and gauge symmetry is the noun but they are describing the same thing?  So they are describing the same concept ?i.e equal ?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: More precisely: G invariance is that a theory doesn't change under G symmetry. Here, G can be any algebraic group.